# Relation between Racah coefficients and Clebsch-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory

In the book [Relativistic quantum mechanics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/relativistic-quantum-mechanics/07610FA26C1D8BCE9434A3B2716099B5)  by Paul Strange he has at page 56 the following formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
& ((2 e+1)(2 f+1))^{1 / 2} W(a b c d ; e f) C(a f c ; \alpha, \beta+\delta) \\
& \quad=\sum_\beta C(a b e ; \alpha, \beta) C(e d c ; \alpha+\beta, \delta) C(b d f ; \beta, \delta)
\end{aligned} \tag {2.123b}
$$
where $W$ are the Racah coeficients and $C$ are the Clebsch Gordan coeficients.

Now at page 342 he has
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I_{\lambda_2, \lambda_1, l}^{m_{j_2}, m_{j_1}}=(-1)^{\lambda_1+\lambda_2-l-j_2-m_{j_2}}\left(\frac{2 j_1+1}{2 l+1}\right)^{1 / 2} \times \\
& \quad \sum_{s= \pm \frac{1}{2}} C\left(j_1 \frac{1}{2} \lambda_1 ;-m_{j_1}, s\right) C\left(\frac{1}{2} \lambda_2 j_2 ; s, m_{j_2}-s\right) C\left(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 l ; s-m_{j_1}, m_{j_2}-s\right) 
\end{aligned}
\tag{10.80}
$$
Now by puting $\alpha=m_{j_1}, \beta=s$ and $\delta=m_{j_2}-s$ he claims that he can use formula $(2.123b)$ to eliminate the sum in $s$ on formula $(10.80)$

I can not see why his claim should be true because since in formula $(2.123b)$ ,$\delta$ is fixed that is ,it does not depend on $\beta$.